# Stop extra space on carriage return in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I hit return in notepad++ the cursor goes to the next line, as I would expect, but it also adds an additional space on the new line. Is there anywhere in preferences that I can stop this behaviour. I don't want a space. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the context this could simply be auto indentation.

Comment: Thanks. That was it: Settings>Preferences>MISC uncheck auto indentaion.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

Settings → Preferences → Auto-Completion; uncheck auto indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this thread: http://ehc.ac/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/11fa1f14/

There's a macro called "Trim trailing and save" with the short cut **Alt+Shift+S**. Obviously it has appeared during installation. It's relatively convinient.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it now is: *Settings* -> *Preferences* -> *Auto-Completion* -> uncheck *Auto-indent*.

[image]